# hide div on delete ajax rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a button in my rails app that generates a div with an image and a delete button in it. 
When I click delete I want the div to be destroyed and to disappear with ajax.

html.erb:

```
<div class="button">
    <%= link_to "Generate Mockups",  { :controller => :ideas, :action => 
 :generate_mockups, remote: true, :id => idea.permalink} %>
  </div>
  <% idea.mockups.each do |mockup| %>
      <div class="idea-mockup <% if mockup.dirty %>dirty<% end %>">
    <h3><%= mockup.name %></h3>
    <p>
      <%= link_to "Delete", mockup_path(mockup), id: 'delete_mockups',  :method =>:delete, 
 :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this idea?",  :remote => true %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= link_to image_tag(mockup.file.url(:icon)), mockup.file.url, :target => "_blank", 
 :alt => mockup.description, :title => mockup.description %>
    </p>
    <% if mockup.dirty %>
        <p> The art or mockup template has been modified, and this mockup is being 
 recreated </p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

ideas controller :

```
def generate_mockups
    @idea = Idea.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    begin
      @idea.generate_mockups
    rescue Exception => e
     flash[:error] = "There was an error generating the mockups for #{@idea.working_name}! 
 #{e.message}"
    end
respond_to do |format|
  flash.now[:notice] = "Successfully generated mockups for #{@idea.working_name}"
  format.html {redirect_to idea_url(params[:id])}
  format.js
 end
 end
```

mockup controller:
      def destroy
        Mockup.find(params[:id]).destroy
        flash[:notice] = "Mockup destroyed."
        redirect_to mockups_url
     end

When I click the delete button inside the div, I want the mock to be destroyed and hidden with ajax

Comment: It looks like you might possibly have duplicate id's, which would be 100% the reason why only the first one works (only the first one is valid).

Comment: you are miss interpreting me, it disappears once clicking the button after refreshing the page. but if the page is never refreshed it doesn't hide the div when clicking delete. where is this duplication you are talking about?

Comment: Within this block: `<% idea.mockups.each do |mockup| %>` you have `<%= link_to "Delete", mockup_path(mockup), id: 'delete_mockups',` I'm no ror developer, but i'm pretty sure that means for each mockup, you're generating some html that contains a delete button with the id "delete_mockups"

Comment: However, it's likely that this isn't causing a problem due to the inefficient selector you are using: `'a#delete_mockups'`

Comment: it is because each div has a delete button, the js code finds the closest div to the link and hides and deletes it... I believe there is more of an ajax, rails issue here

Comment: Yes, it's likely rails/ajax, but you still have duplicate ids, you should really make that a class and select by classname.

Comment: ok, I will do that, but this is not the issue in question..